# Укокошить

Tags: этимология

Тут спрашивали по поводу слова "уконтрапупить". А меня интересует его синоним - "укокошить". Какая у него этимология?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего: не стоить проводить аналогию с "контрапупить". И значения совпадают лишь частично, и, главное, сфера применения разная. "Укокошить" встречается у Пушкина и Достоевского.

Достоверной этимологии, думаю, нет, как и почти всегда у подобных экспрессивных словечек. Но рискну высказать вресию, что проискодит от общеславянского звукоподражательного(?) "кокош" - петух (или курица), либо напрямую, либо через "кокошник" - головной убор.

На версии родства с "кокош" настаивает и Фасмер, хотя Трубачев частично возражает, предполагая родство с "кокнуть". Последнее, впрочем, тоже может восходить к курице или клюву.